# How to back to window after closed frame with Selenium and PHPUnit?

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I'm testing a page with frame where I click and frame automatically closes. After frame closes, the Selenium can't go back to current window and continue tests.

My test:

```
public function testMyFrame(){
    $this->frame('myFrame'); //Select frame
    $this->byId('myButtonInFrame')->click; //Here myFrame is closed and my page don't have some frame
    $this->byId('otherButton')->click;
}
```

Error:

```
PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: cannot forward the request 127.0.0.1:8080 failed to respond
org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bug was discovery and will be fix. You can see [here](https://github.com/giorgiosironi/phpunit-selenium/issues/339).

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting, is not related to the frame being closed.  The entire window is being closed here.

Please let's make sure to disambiguate "windows" from "frames".  If you switch to a frame, and the frame close, the window closes because the frame is attached to the window.  If a window closes, you are always able to get back.

Nevertheless, the command to get back to the current context is something close to:

```
$this->switchToDefaultContent();
```

(it's probably not named that, but search the doc.  you should find something about "switching to default content")

Comment: I'm using PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase and don't have nothing similar. But have window() and currentWindow(). I already had tried this and didn't worked.

https://github.com/giorgiosironi/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase.php